# Outer merge pandas dataframes with overwrite

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I have two DataFrames `df_old` and `df_new` with same columns `x` (=identifier or index) and `y` (=data).

Now I want to overwrite data in `df_old` which is available in `df_new` + add the data from `df_new` that is not in `df_old`, so basically an outer merge on `x` with overwrite of `y`.

I tried it with `pandas.DataFrame.merge` and `pandas.DataFrame.update` but I am not able to achieve the desired result in one line  or without doing row wise computations.

Example:

```
x = np.array(range(0, 10))
y = np.array(range(0, 10))
df_old = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x,'y':y})

x = np.array(range(5, 15))
y = np.array(range(0, 10))
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x,'y':y})

x = np.array(range(0, 15))
y = np.append(np.array(range(0, 5)), np.array(range(0, 10)))
df_desired = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':x,'y':y})
```

EDIT:
The focus of the solution should be on execution time and memory efficiency . Simple solutions e.g. a one-liner would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a possible efficient solution as it's only using boolean maps but it's still ugly and I would have expected pandas to have a more convenient solution for such tasks:

```
df_desired = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, how='outer', on='x')
df_desired['y'] = df_desired.loc[df_desired['y_y'].isna(), 'y_x'].append(df_desired.loc[df_desired['y_y'].notna(), 'y_y'])
df_desired = df_desired[['x','y']]
```

EDIT: my final solution looks like this:

```
df_desired = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, how='outer', on='x')
df_desired.loc[df_desired['y_y'].isnull(), 'y_y'] = df_desired['y_x']
df_desired = df_desired.drop('y_x', axis=1).rename({'y_y': 'y'}, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

So I would use `pd.merge` as you have suggested, and then process the data to overwrite where possible.

Using your example:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, on="x", how="outer")
>>> df_merged
     x  y_x  y_y
0    0  0.0  NaN
1    1  1.0  NaN
2    2  2.0  NaN
3    3  3.0  NaN
4    4  4.0  NaN
5    5  5.0  0.0
6    6  6.0  1.0
7    7  7.0  2.0
8    8  8.0  3.0
9    9  9.0  4.0
10  10  NaN  5.0
11  11  NaN  6.0
12  12  NaN  7.0
13  13  NaN  8.0
14  14  NaN  9.0
```

Then create a new y column and use the data you would like to overwrite the old data with where applicable:

```
df_merged["y"] = [y if pd.notna(y) else x for x,y in zip(df_merged["y_x"], df_merged["y_y"])]
>>> df_merged
     x  y_x  y_y    y
0    0  0.0  NaN  0.0
1    1  1.0  NaN  1.0
2    2  2.0  NaN  2.0
3    3  3.0  NaN  3.0
4    4  4.0  NaN  4.0
5    5  5.0  0.0  0.0
6    6  6.0  1.0  1.0
7    7  7.0  2.0  2.0
8    8  8.0  3.0  3.0
9    9  9.0  4.0  4.0
10  10  NaN  5.0  5.0
11  11  NaN  6.0  6.0
12  12  NaN  7.0  7.0
13  13  NaN  8.0  8.0
14  14  NaN  9.0  9.0
```

Then just select the correct columns:

```
df_merged = df_merged[["x","y"]]
>>> df_merged
     x    y
0    0  0.0
1    1  1.0
2    2  2.0
3    3  3.0
4    4  4.0
5    5  0.0
6    6  1.0
7    7  2.0
8    8  3.0
9    9  4.0
10  10  5.0
11  11  6.0
12  12  7.0
13  13  8.0
14  14  9.0
```

Comment: absolut valid solution! but I was looking for something without doing row wise computations. I thought there must be some neat pandas method that does this efficiently...

Comment: Yes I would have thought so too but nothing sprang to mind and looking at the merge documentation nothing seems to do the job exactly in one function! I'm going to keep searching :)